# RAILS plugin delegate_belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

anyone could give reference and sample about this plugin **delegate_belongs_to** in rails?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

`delegate_belongs_to` seems to have been replaced by [pahanix's delegates_attributes_to](http://github.com/pahanix/delegates_attributes_to), but the basic idea is as follows.

Say you have an `Office` model in your Rails app which has an `address` field, and you also have an `Employee` model which belongs to an office:

```
class Office < AcitveRecord::Base
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :office
end
```

If you want to find out the address of an employee you would have to do the following:

```
>> emp.office.address
=> "Edinburgh"
```

However, if you had used `delegate_belongs_to` like so:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :office
  delegate_belongs_to :office
end
```

you would get direct access to the attributes of the `Office` model:

```
>> emp.address
=> "Edinburgh"
```

The [github page](http://github.com/pahanix/delegates_attributes_to) details a number of other ways of using the plugin and is worth reading. The original plugin seems to have resided at [faber's github page](http://github.com/faber/delegate_belongs_to).